# first order logic - Fitch Formal Proof Question

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-proofs

I'm doing this by myself over the summer and I'm really confused about construct formal proof with Fitch. Currently stucked on a problem that is asking me to derive
Dodec(f) from Dodec(e), ¬Small(e), and ¬Dodec(e) ∨ Dodec(f) ∨ Small(e). I have a partially constructed proof already. Please help me check my steps and let me know how can I conclude it. [my proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jbd.png)

Edit: Because some lovely person commeneted on how the picture might not be viewable, here is a text version of my proof

1. Dodec(e)
2. ¬Small(e)
3. ¬Dodec(e) ∨ Dodec(f) ∨ Small(e)
4. -subproof ¬Dodec(e)
5. ⊥ (Intro ⊥ 1, 4) - end subproof
6. ¬¬Dodec(e) (¬ Intro 4-5)
7. -subproof Dodec(f)
8. Dodec(f) (Reit 7) - end subproof
9. -subproof Small(e)
10. ¬Small(e) (Reit 2)
11. ⊥ (⊥ Intro 9, 10) - end subproof
12. Dodec(f) (∨ Elim 3, 7-8, 9-11, 4-5)

Thank you guys so so much!!!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Basically you have to apply [Disjunctive Syllogims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) twice to premise ¬Dodec(e) ∨ Dodec(f) ∨ Small(e)